# Programmatically apply the image alt attribue as a class to parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add as a class the image alt attribute to its container element. Markup:

```
<div class="field-group-our-people">
  <div class="field-items even>
   <img alt="John">
  </div>
  <div class="field-items odd>
   <img alt="Kevin">
  </div>
  <div class="field-items even>
   <img alt="Kate">
  </div>
  <div class="field-items odd>
   <img alt="Martin">
  </div>
</div>
```

To be like this:

```
<div class="field-group-our-people">
      <div class="field-items even john>
       <img alt="John">
      </div>
      <div class="field-items odd kevin>
       <img alt="Kevin">
      </div>
      <div class="field-items even kate>
       <img alt="Kate">
      </div>
      <div class="field-items odd martin>
       <img alt="Martin">
      </div>
</div>
```

My Jquery code(but not working):

```
//Add the image alt attribute as class for individual styling
$('.group_our_people .field-item').each(function() {
  var att = $('.group_our_people .field-item img').attr('alt');               
  $(this).addClass(att);        
});
```

What is wrong/missing in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the `img` that is child of the current div (on iteration):

```
var att = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
```

The way you're doing (i.e. repeating the selector), you end up retrieving multiple values, and only the first one is taken into account. So, every div will get its class: "John".

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.field-group_our_people div[class^=".field-items"] img').each(function()
{
  var att = $(this).attr('alt');               
  $(this).parent().addClass(att);        
});
```

Comment: Hi Sayem..thanks for you help but the code is not working in my end. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.field-group-our-people .field-items img').each(function() {
     $(this).parent().addClass( $(this).attr('alt') );
});
```